# Are 'among' and 'of' interchangeable in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am proofreading a book for a museum of archaeology. While I was doing so I came across this sentence and it seems a bit odd but I am not so sure. I need your help;

> "Of the six gold crowns of Silla that have so far been discovered,
>   this one represents the oldest form of the original type and features
>   ornamentation that closely resembles actual tree branches."

I made some revision:

"*Among* the six gold crowns of Silla that have been discovered *so far* *does* this one represent the oldest form of the original type, *and it* features ornamentation that closely resembles actual tree branches."

I have two questions:

1. It seems more natural to me that'among' is used instead of 'of' here. Is it? or both of them are okay?
2. In this case where this adverbial phrase "Of the six gold crowns of Silla that have so far been discovered,"comes in front of everything else, shouldn't you put the verb in front of the subject as it is a case of inversion?

Thank you in advance.

appreciatedly,

Yeseul Shin

Comment: Changing "of" to "among" is purely a style choice and makes no real difference. The same is true of "and it…"


Sorry and "… does this one…" looks pretentious at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among - Denotes a belonging of a person or a thing to a group.
Example:He is among the few who completely understand the subject.
Denotes a sharing of a common feature in a group.

Of - The word of is used with plural subject  referring to one of many.

Among all the people,only two have passed the exam.

Only two out of all the people have passed the exam.

Of all the people,he is the youngest = he is the yongest of all = he is the youngest among all.

"Of the six gold crowns of Silla that have so far been discovered, this one represents the oldest form of the original type and features ornamentation that closely resembles actual tree branches."
Can be written as 
"Out of all the...(readers will sense that writer is going to say something is distinct)
"Among all six...
"Among the six...
More Examples
Of the six boys he is the best
Among the six boys he is the best

Comment: So if I understood you correctly,technically there's nothing wrong with the original sentence but you would recommend adding "_out_ of _all_" in order to make it more clear?

Comment: Yes, sometimes different words have Same Meanings

Comment: I know. Anyhow, thank you so much for the answer. It helps me a lot :).